# What is your ideal EQ for editing dialogue?

Tags: adr, dialogue, editing, techniques

Just like the title, what is your Ideal EQ for editing dialogue?  Q3? Rennaissance? Audio Track?  Sonnox?  Stock DAW?

It seems like sometimes you might want a transparent EQ.

Comment: I didn't know EQ could edit dialogue. Do you mean touch-ups of mis-matching lines of dialogue? Or EQ to use in the final mix? In that case, I already asked "What is your favorite EQ" - lots of good answers there.

Comment: right, I did mean touching up or making it sound good.  I didnt even know what the process is.

Answer (score 6):

You would not want EQ on your tracks while editing dialogue, as eg you need to hear how the backgrounds change between takes/perspectives etc so that you know overlaps & fill are working...

And for film, EQ on a dub stage is a lot different to EQ in near field monitors... 
best to leave it to the mixer

Answer (score 3):

I 100% agree with Tim.  Let the stage make the decision.

The **ONLY** EQ I ever (rarely) use in the edit is a 12-18dB/oct high pass rolloff at 80Hz on the Master if the production mixer left me with some nasty low end, but that's only if the low end is so bad that you can actually see the modulations and its making every single minute sub-frame edit snap regardless of the crossfade I gave it (like for cleaning out ticks and lip smacks).  In my experiences this frequency area is where it tends gets rolled off in a premix, so that's the only reason I safely use that curve when I cut when the production quality calls for me to do so.

This type of EQ is strictly of troubleshooting nature only.  And normally production mics/mixers are set during shows to roll off at 60Hz or 80Hz, so normally there's nothing down there to be even rolled off by the time everything arrives via dailies and OMF.  But on those rare occasions where the mic or the mixer rolloff was completely disabled and low-end galore made it onto the recording, I'll be simulating in effect what the mixer should have probably been doing by using this EQ setting.

Now, if I am dealing with someone's voice who does extend down below 80, or if there's no obnoxiously bad low end problem overall in the dailies, I'll forgo the EQ all together and follow exactly what Tim says.

Answer (score 1):

DMG Equality is great

Answer (score 1):

When we mix dialogue units we use the pro tools EQ7 and if need to notch waves Q10.

Been meaning to look at Equality but worried about CPU / dly

Answer (score 0):

I personally use FabFilter Pro Q as surgical tool...

Answer (score 0):

Left field opinion...

If you choose to not EQ at all during dia editing you will very likely use too long fades and transitions,  and use too much fill to be able to make the dia sound great. Since on the stage they will EQ and correct tonal (in)balance. So the fades to hide those tonal differences will be longer than necessary and might smear the sound more than necessary.

Otoh... You need great calibrated monitoring that translates well to get anywhere near close... Headphones does NOT work.
You always have to talk to your mixer if attempting to prep EQ!
You also need a good time of dub stage experience to hear how it translates.